# SQL query that searches two columns (2 & 3) if record is found display column 3

Tags: sql

I need a SQL query that searches column 2 through column 3 if a record is found (either an exact match or a value between the value of column 2 and column 3) return corresponding value from column 1

for example

```
Column1     Column2     Column3 

Jane Doe    123456        123459

John Doe    123460        123460 

Frank Doe   123461        123482
```

if I type in `123457` I need it to show me `Jane Doe`

if I type in `123460` I need it to show me `John Doe`

thank you,

Comment: select column1 from table where [column 2] <= [column 3]                 this isn't working as expected

Comment: If you add (Matt Doe, 123465, 123455), what's then the expected result if you type 123460?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT
    Column1
 FROM 
    TableName
 WHERE
    123460 BETWEEN column2 AND column3;
```

Answer (score 1):

To take care of the case when column3 < column2, do `BETWEEN SYMMETRIC`:

```
select Column1
from tablename
where 123460 between symmetric column2 and column3
```

Will also return the row (Matt Doe, 123465, 123455)!

Answer (score 0):

Have you written any code for this?
You are supposed to post your code here so we can help fix it.

Anyway, you can do this:

```
SELECT column1
FROM tableName
WHERE column2 >= VALUE
AND column3 <= VALUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE abc
(
column1 varchar(20),
column2 integer,
column3 integer
);

insert into abc values ('Jane Doe', 123456, 123459);

insert into abc values ('John Doe', 123460, 123460);

insert into abc values ('Frank Doe', 123461, 123482);

select column1 from abc where column2 <= 123457 AND column3 >= 123457;
select column1 from abc where column2 <= 123460 AND column3 >= 123460;
```

Comment: this isn't working I keep getting no record found when running the first query select column1 from abc where column2 >= 123457 and column3 <= 1234567;